# JavaFX simulating product survey

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, product, survey

I'm making a simulated survey about 5 products. Currently learning JavaFX for high school. The task is to generate 1000 random numbers from 1 to 5 and I have to print the result for each customers's choice in little circles that represent 10 votes.

Edit: I want to print one 'O' for every 10 votes that have been generated but only get one 'O' even if there are enough generated numbers.

```
    //Rounding up the numbers that have been generated
    int a = (int) Math.ceil(prodOne / 10.0);
    int b = (int) Math.ceil(prodTwo / 10.0);
    int c = (int) Math.ceil(prodThree / 10.0);
    int d = (int) Math.ceil(prodFour / 10.0);
    int e = (int) Math.ceil(prodFive / 10.0);

    //for-loop to print one 'O' for every 10 votes
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        s += "O ";
    }
    lblProductOne.setText(s);

    s="";
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++){
        s += "O ";
    }
    lblProductTwo.setText(s);

    s="";
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++){
        s += "O ";
    }
    lblProductThree.setText(s);

    s="";
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        s += "O ";
    }
    lblProductFour.setText(s);

    s="";
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++){
        s += "O ";
    }
    lblProductFive.setText(s);
}
```

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully it's more clear now. I want to print one 'O' for every 10 votes for each number

Comment: I am still having a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to print tekst like this for example: OOOOOOOOOO which represents 100 votes (10 for each O) and want to do this for each product (5 in total) but I'm only getting one O  for each product

Comment: What does the prodsxxxx equal to?

Comment: This is Label where the text (the O's) should be printed to

Comment: What does prodOne, etc equal?

Comment: These are all variables of type int that count the number of 'votes' for each product, they are the divided by 10 so that every 10 votes will be multiplied by one 'O' and thus would like to get a string of O's equal to the votes (10 votes/O)

Comment: I know what they are and their purpose. I want to know what they equal. The best thing for you to do is go to the help section and learn how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll do that

Comment: I recommend printing the value of each variable before the `for` loops; this will help confirm they are actually giving you a correct value. ie: `System.out.println(a);`

Comment: Haven't tried that one yet, thx